# Android, setting up a Linux build environment, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 package have unmet dependencies

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source, android-build

I'm trying to setting up a Linux build environment for AOSP. I have Ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64 distributive. I do everything in accordance with the instructions given [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html). 
I typed in the terminal command to install the necessary packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
```

then I get an error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7)
                        Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So the logical thing to do is `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, however then get the following message:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal libxatracker1-lts-quantal ubuntu-desktop xorg
 xserver-xorg-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-quantal
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-quantal
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386
 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libllvm3.0:i386
 libpciaccess0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

My concern is the packages it's going to REMOVED. Seems to me that if I allow the removal I loose my desktop environment.

Anybody have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem. Do the following, install all packages except `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
```

Install `libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy:i386` instead of `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy:i386
```

Now you have correct AOSP build environment and don't loose desktop environment.

Comment: the next step in source.android.com is to create a symbolic link:
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
but after installing what you said, there is still no libGL.so.1.
is this alright?
or do I miss anything?
thanks

Comment: "and don't loose desktop environment" means you're compiling AOSP on ubuntu desktop?! Do you get something like below line after running 'lunch' command in your terminal? ;[arm-productname-user] root@ubuntu

Comment: As of right now, it seems that `libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy:i386` can be replaced with `libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty:i386`. If it's not replaced, it will start the same dependency troubles.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave out the troubling package and install the recommended one afterwards. Important is now to make sure, that your desktop is not missing after reboot.
Here is what I did:

> sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
>   zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
>   libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 \   libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib
>   mingw32 tofrodos \   python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc
>   zlib1g-dev:i386

then:

> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386

and then:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg